# GCC style weak linking in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, weak-linking

GCC has the ability to make a symbol link weakly via `__attribute__((weak))`.  I want to use the a weak symbol in a static library that users can override in their application.  A GCC style weak symbol would let me do that, but I don't know if it can be done with visual studio.

Does Visual Studio offer a similar feature?

Comment: See [Windows Static Library with Default Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097961/windows-static-library-with-default-functions). Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: See the [answer by Michael Burr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2290843/321013) -- MSVC actually *defaults* to this behaviour. If you override a symbol that is already defined in a dependency lib, the symbol in the `.lib` will be silently ignored.

Comment: VC++ does not expose an explicit way of declaring symbols as weak – but there are two alternatives that *come close*. Check: https://ofekshilon.com/2014/02/10/linker-weak-symbols/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MSVC++ has `__declspec(selectany)` which covers part of the functionality of weak symbols: it allows you to define multiple identical symbols with external linkage, directing the compiler to choose any one of several available. However, I don't think MSVC++ has anything that would cover the other part of weak symbol functionality: the possibility to provide "replaceable" definitions in a library.

This, BTW, makes one wonder how the support for standard replaceable `::operator new` and `::operator delete` functions works in MSVC++.

Comment: Does MSVC++ have something like this macro that works with `main()`, in order to let any code including *this* file override `main()`?

Comment: `::operator new` ships as object code inside `nothrownew.obj`. I assume the CRT uses a similar concept to the [`__fltused`-trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/08/10383017.aspx) to have the object code pulled into the module unless it has been defined elsewhere. The classical linker rules for OBJs and LIBs are described at [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/09/10383325.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Fixed link: [Understanding the classical model for linking: You can override an LIB with another LIB, and a LIB with an OBJ, but you can’t override an OBJ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130109-00/?p=5613).

Answer (score 99):

You can do it, here is an example in C:

```
/*
 * pWeakValue MUST be an extern const variable, which will be aliased to
 * pDefaultWeakValue if no real user definition is present, thanks to the
 * alternatename directive.
 */

extern const char * pWeakValue;
extern const char * pDefaultWeakValue = NULL;

#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:_pWeakValue=_pDefaultWeakValue")
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  Can you find some documentation to back it up?

Comment: It is an undocumented feature. I've stumbled upon it accidentally while browsing msvcrt source code.

Comment: @Ringo If the `pWeakValue` *is* defined already, can it still be replaced by the `alternatename` option.

Comment: At least with  VS2019, this also works for functions, provided they are declared `extern "C"` in C++ code.  At least I couldn't get it to work with mangled C++ function names, but it did work with `extern "C"` functions.

Comment: Raymond Chen wrote a blog post about /ALTERNATENAME linker switch https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200731-00/?p=104024

Comment: The problem is, `pDefaultWeakValue` and `pWeakValue` are 2 different symbols.  So this approach only allows you to define a customized version of `pWeakValue` and fall back to `pDefaultWeakValue` if not. If there's one function `pWeakValue()` that is defined and used, you cannot replace it without changing the implementation name to `pDefaultWeakValue()` and provide your own implementation of `pWeakValue()` because there's only 1 symbol name.

Comment: @dgnuff Re: "with VS2019, this also works for functions": can you provide a demo? In C I cannot make it work: https://godbolt.org/z/xqzdM51dc. Any ideas?

Comment: @dgnuff As I understand, in contrast with GCC's `__attribute__((weak))`, MSVC's `/alternatename` does not have an effect on compiler. If `f` is a `weak` attributed function, then GCC does _not_ optimize `if (f)` to `if (1)`. If `f` is a function with `/alternatename`, then MSVC optimizes `if (f)` to `if (1)`.

Comment: @pmor As Michael Burr points out in his answer, no action is needed to get this behavior to work under MSVC.  https://godbolt.org/z/zcsKMf95x  I've overridden `puts()` there simply by defining it in the source file, and my version is used in preference to the one in the standard library

Comment: I did not need to add '_' before the symbols in the linker comment.

Answer (score 16):

MSVC used to behave such that if a symbol is defined in a .obj file and a .lib it would use the one on the .obj file without warning.  I recall that it would also handle the situation where the symbol is defined in multiple libs it would use the one in the library named first in the list.

I can't say I've tried this in a while, but I'd be surprised if they changed this behavior (especially that .obj defined symbols override symbols in .lib files).

Comment: A brief test with VS 2010 RC indicates that the behavior I described is still there.

Comment: In a way I prefer this behavior to the weak attribute. This has always been the behavior in MS compilers as far as I know (been using MS compiler since 1988 (C5.0). I was puzzled by this when I came across it in GCC  a few years ago. I think it's logical to use the first occurrence of the function found when linking although care has to be taken that you are linking the function you think you are.

Comment: Why can't Microsoft make this more *explicit* ? And I can't find any official document describing this behavior.  I am wondering if this is by design or by accident...

Comment: @MichaelBurr Twelve years later, the current MSVC compiler is still working this way: https://godbolt.org/z/4x9Pz8bvb

Answer (score 5):

The only way i know. Place each symbol in a separate library. User objects with overrides also must be combined to library. Then link all together to an application. User library must be specified as input file, your lib's  must  be transfered to linker  using `/DEFAULTLIB:` option.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130109-00/?p=5613):

> ... if a needed symbol can be satisfied without consulting a library,
> then the *OBJ in the library* will not be used. **This lets you override a
> symbol in a library by explicitly placing it an OBJ. You can also
> override a symbol in a library to putting it in another library that
> gets searched ahead of the one you want to override.** But you can’t
> override a symbol in an explicit OBJ, because those are part of the
> initial conditions.

This behavior results from the algorithm adopted by the linker.

So for short, to override a function,

- With GCC, you must use the `__attribute__((weak))`. You cannot rely on the input order of object files into the linker to decide which function implementation is used.
- With VS toolchain, you can rely on the order of the object/lib files and you must place your implementation of the function before the LIB that implements the original function. And you can put your implementation as an OBJ or LIB.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an MS-VC equivalent to this attribute. See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505028/add-weak-function-references-for-visual-c-c. I'm going to suggest something horrible: reading the purpose of it here: http://www.kolpackov.net/pipermail/notes/2004-March/000006.html it is essentially to define functions that, if their symbols exist, are used, otherwise, are not, so...

Why not use pre-processor for this purpose, with the huge caveat of "if you need to do this at all"? (I'm not a fan of recommending pre-processor).

Example:

```
#ifdef USE_MY_FUNCTION
     extern void function();
#endif
```

then call appropriately in the application logic, surrounded by `#ifdef` statements. If your static library is linked in, as part of the linking in process, tweak the defines to define USE_MY_FUNCTION.

Not quite a direct equivalent and very ugly but it's the best I can think of.