# MSVC linker equivalent of --wrap

Tags: c, visual-c++, ld, visual-c++-2008

Background: I'm dealing with some legacy systems on msvc9, and there are problems with floating point to int conversions. It emits a `__ftol2_sse` instruction which is an undefined reference if not compiling for SSE.

The only way to suppress this is with the `/QIfist` option which performs the conversion inline, without calls to any `ftol()`. However, those inline conversions have a different rounding algorithm, and thus cause problems when used with the existing code. That, and they emit unsuppressible 'deprecated' warnings to cl.exe stderr.

The workaround I have is:

```
// Declare a regular _ftol() function that is present.
long __cdecl _ftol(double); 
// Define _ftol2_sse() to be the regular one.
long __cdecl _ftol2_sse(double f) { return _ftol(f); }
```

And that works nicely. However, some builds do have `_ftol2_sse` defined, in which case I get multiple definitions, and it's a pain to figure that out in the code.

---

I was hoping to do something like `--wrap __ftol2_sse` from `ld`, and just override the behavior on all builds. Is anything like this possible on MSVC?

Comment: Just put it in a .lib, link it last.

Comment: @HansPassant But if a default implementation is already provided, it will report multiple definitions. I don't think MSVC has a way to define weak symbols. Does it?

Comment: Sort of. The undocumented [`/ALTERNATENAME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529277) linker option.

Comment: @cremno According to your link, it seems the `/ALTERNATENAME` can only work **if there's no definition present yet**. If the function is already defined, maybe it cannot be replaced. Anyway, I didn't try it, just some literal deduction. According to here (https://ofekshilon.com/2014/02/10/linker-weak-symbols/), "*it is hardly a replacement*".

Comment: As [Raymond Chen notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200731-00/?p=104024), `/ALTERNATENAME` indeed works if and only if there's no definition found. That is indeed the solution here: you define `__ftol2_sse_fallback`, and use `/alternatename:__ftol2_sse=__ftol2_sse_fallback`. Now the fallback is used in the non-SSE case.