# Compile C code without it's main function

Tags: c, compilation, program-entry-point

So I have several files for a University Project I'm working on; each file has several functions and a `main` function for testing purposes. However some of the files need to use functions from the others which gives linker complaints about multiple `main` declarations as to be expected. I was wondering if there was a way to compile these files to an object file without compiling the `main` function along the way, basically stripping out `main` to leave only the usable functions.

An example (not one of my actual files which are quite large), for each I'm assuming the existence of a header file which contains a declaration of `foo` and `bar` respectively:

```
//File foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

//Assumes the user gives 2 integer inputs
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &x);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &y);
    printf("foo(%d, %d) = %d\n", x, y, foo(x,y));
}

//File bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int bar(int x, int y, int z);
{
    return foo(x, y) * z;
}

//Assums the user gives 3 integer inputs
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y, z;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &x);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &y);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &z);
    printf("bar(%d, %d, %d) = %d\n", x, y, z, bar(x, y, z));
}
```

Is it possible to compile `foo.c` to an object file so that I could call `gcc bar.c foo.o` and get an executable for `bar.c`?

Comment: only compile, don't link...

Comment: You can put `main` inside something like `#ifdef TEST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an `#ifdef` on a symbol that you define only if you are compiling the file to generate the "test executable", and not when you use the file along with others; I've seen this being used for quick functional tests on small libraries.

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

#ifdef COMPILE_MAIN
//Assumes the user gives 2 integer inputs
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &x);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &y);
    printf("foo(%d, %d) = %d\n", x, y, foo(x,y));
}
#endif
```

Now you can do

```
gcc -DCOMPILE_MAIN foo.c -o foo.x
```

to make an executable `foo.x` that you can call directly to test `foo`, and you can do

```
gcc foo.c bar.c main.c -o yourapp.x
```

to make an executable using the other files (including the one with the "real" application `main`) without complaints of multiply defined symbols.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try this, but this looks like precisely what I want. I'm putting together a makefile to do all this so at least I won't have to keep typing this all out. 

Edit: I'll have to try this out tomorrow though, so I'll accept your answer as soon as I've been able to test this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling your code using gcc or clang, you can declare the test `main`s as a weak symbol:

```
extern void main(int argc, char ** argv) __attribute__((weak));
void main(int argc, char ** argv) { ... }
```

The weak `main` will be used only in absence of a strong `main`.

For Visual Studio (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529277/1329652)):

```
// in foo.cpp
extern "C" void main(int argc, char ** argv;
extern "C" void defaultMainFoo(int argc, char ** argv)
// different name for each file
{ ... }
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:_main=_defaultMainFoo");
```

`/alternatename` means that the linker will use `defaultMain` for `main` if `main` is not elsewhere provided.

Answer (score 0):

While putting `#ifdef` around your `main` functions works, IMO it's not the correct approach, especially since ...

> [..] my actual files which are quite large [..]

The reasonable thing would be to separate your code into logical, reusable parts and to put each of these (small) parts into separate files.

A small example: Say you have a project `foo` which you're doing for your university, and part of it is to implement a linked list. The reasonable thing to do would be to create (at least) two source files, `foo.c` and `list.c`, and put the project specific parts (even if it's just some testing) into `foo.c` and all code regarding the implementation of your linked list into `list.c`. The interface of your linked list (i.e. probably some `struct ...` declaration, and functions to create and modify lists) is then put into a header file, `list.h`, which you include from any file needing linked list, such as a future project `bar`:

**list.c**

```
struct list * create_list(void) {
   // awesome code
}
// and more awesome code
```

**list.h**

```
struct list {
   // an awesome list
};
struct list * create_list(void); // <- only a declaration
// more awesome declarations
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
  // awesome use of the list
  return 0;
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
  // also awesome
  return 0;
}
```

Then you can either:

**a)** Compile each source file separately, and link the resulting object files together:

```make
gcc -c list.c
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o list.o
```

This is a way that's also perfectly expressible with make, in fact at least in GNU Make there's even an implicit rule to compile C files to object files (`%.o: %.c`).

Without link time optimization you may lose some optimizations with this approach. If your projects require different compiler flags, then this isn't a good approach.

**b)** Assemble a command line with the needed source files and do a single computation:

```make
gcc -o foo foo.c list.c
```

You can do this with make, too, using for example a variable `FOO_DEPENDENCIES := list.c`.

Note that compile times will be far greater using this method.