# Cygwin: why POSIX symbols in libc.a are strong symbols?

Tags: cygwin, posix

On Cygwin POSIX symbols in `libc.a` are strong symbols (e.g. `accept`):

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libc.a | grep 'accept' -w
0000000000000000 T accept
```

while on Linux they are weak symbols (e.g. `accept`):

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a |& grep 'accept' -w
accept.o:
0000000000000000 W accept
                 U accept
                 U accept
                 U accept
                 U accept
```

Note: having POSIX symbols in `libc.a` may be a bit unexpected.

However, why in Cygwin's `libc.a` POSIX symbols are *strong* symbols?

Example: If user has `mylib.a` containing the definition of `accept` and the `mylib.a` goes *after* the `libc.a` in the list of command line arguments, then the `accept` from the `libc.a` may be (and usually is) selected.

---

UPD. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2290838/1778275:

> MSVC++ has `__declspec(selectany)` which covers part of the functionality of weak symbols.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

Weak Symbol are not available on COFF PE binary.
It is also one of the reason why all symbols must be defined at compilation time.

Comment: Is "weak symbol" == "weak external"? The [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/03wi/lectures/LinkerFiles/coff.pdf) has section 5.5.3. "Auxiliary Format 3: Weak Externals".