# multiple definition of inline function

Tags: c, inline

I have gone through some posts related to this topic but was not able to sort out my doubt completely. This might be a very naive question.

I have a header file `inline.h` and two translation units `main.cpp` and `tran.cpp`.

Details of code are as below

#### inline.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER__
#include <stdio.h>
extern inline int func1(void)
{ return 5; }

static inline int func2(void)
{ return 6; }

inline int func3(void)
{ return 7; }
#endif
```

#### main.c

```
#define <stdio.h>
#include <inline.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",func1());
    printf("%d\n",func2());
    printf("%d\n",func3());
    return 0;
}
```

#### tran.cpp

```
//(note that the functions are not inline here)
#include <stdio.h>
int func1(void)
{ return 500; }

int func2(void)
{ return 600; }

int func3(void)
{ return 700; }
```

The above code compiles in g++, but does not compile in gcc (even if you make changes related to gcc like changing the code to .c, not using any C++ header files, etc.). The error displayed is "duplicate definition of inline function - func3".

Can you clarify why this difference is present across compilers?

Also, when you run the program (g++ compiled) by creating two separate compilation units (`main.o` and `tran.o`) and create an executable `a.out`, the output obtained is:

> 500
>   6
>   700

Why does the compiler pick up the definition of the function which is not inline. Actually, since `#include` is used to "add" the inline definition I had expected `5,6,7` as the output. My understanding was during compilation since the inline definition is found, the function call would be "replaced" by inline function definition.

Can you please tell me in detailed steps the process of compilation and linking which would lead us to `500,6,700` output. I can only understand the output 6.

Comment: Aren't you missing a "#define __HEADER__" after "#ifndef __HEADER__" ??

Comment: What command line switches are you passing to GCC? The specification of `inline` in C99 is different from the legacy GCC-specific extension. Which specification are you trying to use?

Comment: 1) `#ifndef __HEADER__` (preprocessor) identifiers beginning with one or more underscores are reserved for the language ore implementation. 2) which language, C or C++?

Comment: Your example is missing `#define __HEADER__`. Also, here is a link (in my opinion it might be helpful): http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html

Answer (score 13):

This answer is divided into the following sections:

1. How to reproduce the `duplicate definition of inline function - func3` problem and why.
2. Why defintion of `func3` is a duplicate instead of `func1`.
3. Why it compiles using `g++`

---

### How to produce the duplicate definition of inline function - func3 problem

The problem can be successfully reproduced by

1. Rename `tran.cpp` to `tran.c`
2. Compile with `gcc -o main main.c tran.c`

**@K71993 is actually compiling using the old gnu89 inline semantics, which is different from C99.** The reason for renaming `tran.cpp` to `tran.c` is to tell the gcc driver to treat it as `C` source instead of `C++` source.

---

### Why definition of func3 is a duplicate instead of func1.

#### GNU 89 inline semantics

The following text is quoted from [GCC Document: An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Inline.html#Inline) explains why `func3` is a duplicate definition instead of `func1`, since `func3` (instead of `func1`) is an externally visible symbol (in GNU89 inline semantics)

> **When an inline function is not static, then the compiler must assume that there may be calls from other source files; since a global symbol can be defined only once in any program, the function must not be defined in the other source files,** so the calls therein cannot be integrated. Therefore, a non-static inline function is always compiled on its own in the usual fashion.
>
> If you specify **both inline and extern in the function definition**, then the definition is used only for inlining. **In no case is the function compiled on its own, not even if you refer to its address explicitly. Such an address becomes an external reference, as if you had only declared the function, and had not defined it.**

#### C99 inline semantics

If compiled with C99 standard, i.e., `gcc -o main main.c tran.c -std=c99`, the linker will complain that definition of `func1` is a duplicate due to the reason that **extern inline** in C99 is a external definition as mentioned in other posts and comments.

Please also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/504646) execellent answer about semantic differents between `GNU89 inline` and `C99 inline.`

### Why it compiles using `g++`.

When compiled with `g++`, the source program are considered as `C++` source. Since `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are defined in multiple translation units and their definitions are different, the [One Defintion Rule of C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) is violated. Since the compiler is not required to generate dignostic message when definitions spans multiple translation units, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should post the actual code. The snippets you show don't compile:

- inline.h has `extern inline int func1(void)` That doesn't make any sense.
- main.h has `#define <stdio.h>` I think you meant `include` instead.

Once I fixed those and compiled with gcc, it compiled fine and I got the following output

```
5
6
7
```

When I compile with g++, I get this output:

```
5
6
700
```

That happens because func3() is not static in inline.h

Comment: `extern inline` is used by some compilers to say "inline this if you see a use and can inline, but if you see a use where it cannot be inlined assume that another compilation unit will provide a non-inline version of this function".  Inability to inline could be because the function's address was assigned to a variable or passed to another function.  I believe that gcc header files use `extern inline` quite often.

Comment: @nategoose: `extern inline` is a standard feature of C99 language. It is not about "some compilers". All C99-conformant compilers must recognize `extern inline` definition as an external definition for the function.

Comment: @AndreyT: Some compilers are C99.  :-)  Some that aren't (or aren't in C99 mode) still accept `extern inline`

Answer (score 3):

The compiling error is because there is a duplicate definition of func1();

Because func1() is defined using extern inline, it will produce a external definition.

However, there is also an external definition in tran.c, which cause multiple definition error.

However, func2() and func3() do not produce an external definition, hence no redefinition error.

You might want to look at [here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2003/03/inline.html) http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2003/03/inline.html.

Also, take a note that c++ and c treats inline functions differently, and even in c, different standards (c89 vs. c99) treats inline functions differently.

Comment: As far as I know pure C89 doesn't support inline keyword, there are only some extensions which supports inline, but in this case you're not writing anymore in the pure C89 but in the some dialect of C89.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid from the C++ point of view, since it blatantly violates the One Definition Rule. The only reason you managed to compile it by C++ compiler is the loose error checking in your C++ compiler (it happens to be one of those parts of ODR where "no diagnostic is required").

Your code is not valid C, because it provides duplicate external definition of function `func1`. Note that it is `func1`, not `func3` that is problematic from the C point of view. There's nothing formally wrong with your `func3`. Your `func2` is also OK, as long as the two definitions never "meet" each other in the same translation unit.

One possible reason you might be getting a different diagnostic report from your compiler is  that your C compiler might be supporting `inline` functions in some non-standard compiler-specific way (either a pre-C99 compiler or a modern compiler run in non-standard "legacy" mode).

Frankly, I find it hard to believe you are getting an error report about `func3` from *any* compiler, assuming the code you posted accurately represents what you are trying to compile. Most likely what you posted is *not* the real code.

Answer (score 0):

The compile error you see is actually a linker error.

gcc and g++ are treating `static inline` a little differently.  `inline` was first part of C++ and then made into an extension to many C compilers, before being added to standard C.  The standard semantics could be different, but it could just be the implementations that are different.

It could also have something to do with some crazy stuff that happens with C++ code that gets rid of duplicate template stuff catching other duplicate stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

basically Inline is a late entry to GCC ( I mean c compiler).
    "[ . . . ] An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement any call to the function in the same translation unit. It is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline definition or the external definition."
    — ISO 9899:1999(E), the C99 standard, section 6.7.4