# Possibly not so classic gcc/g++ file error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

to be short and sweet, this is happening right now and has never happened to me before today:

```
  g++ assn1m.c segment.cpp
/tmp/cc2yUKRO.o: In function `bit_to_ascii(char const*, char*)':
segment.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `bit_to_ascii(char const*, char*)'
/tmp/cc2Xgj7t.o:assn1m.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.4/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:115: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Seems like in files assn1m.c and segment.cpp function bit_to_ascii defined...

Comment: i suspect that its in a header that is not protected from multiple inclusions. It is of course completely impossible for us to diagnose tho without seeing any code

Comment: @pm100: There's no way to prevent that sort of double inclusion from two different TUs.  The correct action is to mark the function `inline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two definitions of the function `bit_to_ascii(char const*, char*)`, one of which is in assn1m.c and the other of which is in segment.cpp.  This is often caused by defining it in a header file without `inline` and including it in multiple source files.

Note that in C99, the `inline` specifier works slightly differently than in C++.  You may have to define it as `extern inline` to get it to work properly.

You also didn't define the `main` function anywhere for your program's entry point, or you're not linking in the object file where it's defined, though that's a separate issue from the multiple definitions error.

Comment: What?  In what case in C++ does one ever have to write `extern inline`?

Comment: Not in C++, but in C99: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline).  For a header that needs to be used in C and C++, it would be better to use a macro that expands to either `inline` or `extern inline` depending on whether the code is being compiled as C or C++.

Comment: ah, if it's a C compatable header... I get it