# return makes pointer from integer without a cast - but types are okay?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, inline, extern

Just some code. In one file and its header:

```
// header:
extern char * thessc_config_member_get_config_key(struct config_member_t *m);

// implementation:
inline char * thessc_config_member_get_config_key(struct config_member_t *m) {
    return m->config_key;
}

// another file (.c)
char *key;
key             = thessc_config_member_get_config_key(*ary);
```

[edit]: All required headers are included![/edit]

But gcc with -fsyntax-only tells:

```
 Warnung: Zuweisung erzeugt Zeiger von Ganzzahl ohne Typkonvertierung [standardmäßig aktiviert]
     key             = thessc_config_member_get_config_key(*ary);

 # English: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Can someone explain to me why this happened? I tried to remove `extern` and `inline`, but it won't work either!

Regards.

Comment: I am confuse what is wrong, include header file and add declaration in .C file it will work. Deleting my answer

Comment: I'm confused, too. I moved my `inline`d functions to the header file, which is better (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504316/what-happens-with-a-extern-inline-function?noredirect=1). But anyway, the upper example should compile, shoun't it?

Comment: what is the datatype of "config_key"? Is it a character or a character array?

Comment: your translation of the error message is wrong, it should be "assignment" instead of "return".

Comment: @NithinBhaskar it is `char *` indeed, so no error here. 
@JensGustedt thank you for your correction!

Answer (score 0):

`*ary` looks wrong to me. You probably mean `&ary` as the argument to your function.

Comment: `ary` is of type `struct config_member_t**`, so no, I think I'm right with this!

Comment: you didn't tell us beforehand so I couldn't know