# Differences of the inline-keyword in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Consider the following C++-code with an `inline`-function:

```
// this function is in a header-file:
// recursion prevents inlining
inline int calc(int k){
    if(k<=1) return 1;
    return calc(k-1)+calc(k-2);
}

// this function is in a source-file:
int fun(int k){
    return calc(k);
}
```

Here I use recursion, to simulate the case when compiler was not able to inline the function `calc`.

The resulting assembly (compiled with `-Os`, see [live on https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/z/7nvaeWTWs)):

```
...
        .weak   calc(int)
        .type   calc(int), @function
calc(int):
    // some assembler


       .text
        .globl  fun(int)
        .type   fun(int), @function
fun(int):
...
        jmp     calc(int)
```

As expected, the compiler was not able to inline `calc`, and thus emitted code for it, but due to `inline`-keyword it becomes a weak symbol.

Compiling the same code as C, produces a different result  (with `-Os`,see [live on https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/z/ob3bc8f5o)):

```
.Ltext0:
        .globl  fun
        .type   fun, @function
fun:
...
        jmp     calc
```

The most notable difference: there is no code emitted for `calc`, so basically the linker will not able to link the executable, as the definition of `calc` is missing.

Obviously, `inline` means different things in C compared to C++.

What are differences for `inline` in C compared to C++? How the definition of `calc` should be done, that it can be used in a header in C and C++ at the same time?

Comment: Inline is an interesting mess. [And there are more kinds of it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/what-does-extern-inline-do)

Comment: See the linked question's answers for a "just make it work" variant.

Comment: If you try `__attribute((always_inline))` it will give you the error: `error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' 'int calc(int)': recursive inlining`.. Alternatively specify `extern` and it'll do what the C++ one does. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline See "Notes" section for difference.

Comment: comparing `inline` behavior with `-Os` flag looks a bit weird - inlining often results in larger code size and `-Os` is a flag to minimize the code size. so it looks like a bit different heuristics, it looks more natural to check with `-O2`.

Comment: @dewaffled I have chosen -Os because the resulting assembler is clearest. The inline function is chosen in such a way that it will not be Inlined no matter which optimization level.

Comment: Yep they are different. Basically the C++ version means "it's a weak symbol" and the C version means "no weak symbols; if you need a symbol, define a strong symbol separately". That us, create a separate extern function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504316/what-happens-with-an-extern-inline-function

Answer (score 4):

While the `inline`-keyword has the same goal in C and C++: to provide the definition of a function at compile time in multiple translation units, these languages use different methods to cope with its fallout - multiple definitions of the same symbol in different translation units.

When the C- or C++-compiler really inlines the `inline`-function in a translation unit, its definition is no longer needed and no corresponding symbol is emitted. As for example here:

```
inline int fun(){return 2;}

int doit(){
    return fun();
}
```

the resulting assembler is ([live](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jvWrTr6MP))

```
doit():
        movl    $2, %eax
        ret
```

However, when the function don't get inlined, the C++-standard mandates among other things the following:

1. There may be more than one definition of an inline function in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and all definitions are identical.
2. The function has the same address in every translation unit.

This more or less describes a [weak symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970423/5769463) - and no surprise, C++-compiler emits a weak symbol in the OP's code -  it has to, because the C++-standard doesn't guarantee, that this symbol will be defined in another translation unit.

On the other hand, the C-standard gurantees, that the definition of the inline-function must be provided in another translation unit(i.e. has external linkage) and thus (in order to avoid multiple definition of the same symbol) nothing is emited for the inline function - it is just called.

Thus, there must be a c-file, in which the function is "instantiated" via

```
inline int calc(int k)
```

This doesn't work well with the idea of having a header-only library. An alternative is, the use internal linkage via `static`-keyword, i.e.

```
static inline int calc(int k){
    if(k<=1) return 1;
    return calc(k-1)+calc(k-2);
}
```

This will emit a local symbol in every translation unit (if not inlined), independent of whether compiled as C or C++. That means, there are multipe definitions (i.e. in every translation object the function has a different address) of the same function, which will possible lead to a bigger executable, and is a setback for compared to C++-default behavior.

An alternative is to use the following definiton of `inline`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define INLINE inline
#else
    #define INLINE static inline
#endif
```

and use as

```
INLINE int calc(int k){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extern inline int calc(int k){
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3McjjT54T

Comment: I think OP is looking for something that can be put into a header and used by multiple translation units. `extern inline` is not it.