# GCC "multiple definition" errors when linking with external library

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries

I'm trying to use a library (Watt-32, if it's relevant), which fails to link for some reason. I've compiled the library and as a quick "hello world" test, I'm trying to compile the following file:

```
#include <tcp.h>
int main() { sock_init(); }
```

This causes GCC to produce a *long* list of `multiple definition` errors, in the library's own source files:

```
D:\projects\test-tcp>c++ -Iinclude test-tcp.cpp -Llib -lwatt

lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `_ntohl':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:63: multiple definition of `__ntohl'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:63: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `_ntohs':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:73: multiple definition of `__ntohs'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:73: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `get_fs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:736: multiple definition of `get_fs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:736: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `get_gs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:744: multiple definition of `get_gs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:744: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `set_fs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:751: multiple definition of `set_fs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:751: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(rs232.o): In function `set_gs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:757: multiple definition of `set_gs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:757: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `_ntohl':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:63: multiple definition of `__ntohl'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:63: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `_ntohs':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:73: multiple definition of `__ntohs'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/../inc/sys/swap.h:73: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `get_fs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:736: multiple definition of `get_fs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:736: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `get_gs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:744: multiple definition of `get_gs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:744: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `set_fs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:751: multiple definition of `set_fs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:751: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(ports.o): In function `set_gs_reg':
D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:757: multiple definition of `set_gs_reg'
lib\libwatt.a(pctcp.o):D:\msys64\home\JW\watt32\src/misc.h:757: first defined here
lib\libwatt.a(language.o): In function `_ntohl':
[... etc ...]
```

I must be doing something wrong here, but what exactly? It seems like a problem with the library itself..?

edit: These functions are defined as follows in the library source: (implementation omitted, it's all inline assembly code)

```
extern __inline__ WORD get_fs_reg (void)     { /* ... */ }
extern __inline__ WORD get_gs_reg (void)     { /* ... */ }
extern __inline__ void set_fs_reg (WORD sel) { /* ... */ }
extern __inline__ void set_gs_reg (WORD sel) { /* ... */ }
/*@unused@*/ extern __inline__ unsigned long __ntohl (unsigned long x)  { /* ... */ }
/*@unused@*/ extern __inline__ unsigned short __ntohs (unsigned short x) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: The problem could be with function definitions in header files. Have a look at the code where `get_fs_reg` and `get_gs_reg` are defined, in `misc.h` (post that code in the question perhaps). Maybe they are not marked as `inline` when they should be. Also, C and C++ behave differently w.r.t. inline functions. so if this library was a C library it's possible that the headers may need some change to be usable from C++.

Comment: Also try making a C program that includes the header and see if the same errors come up

Comment: @M.M, all these functions are actually marked `__inline__`, and compiled with -O2. I've added their definitions to the question. Compiling the test file as plain C doesn't make any difference. (which I guess makes the c++ tag somewhat irrelevant)

Comment: See if there is a newer version of the library and headers. The changelog mentions "misc.h change: Watcom uses 'i64' suffix for 64-bit values.". I wonder if both 32 bit and 64 bit functions are somehow being compiled into the same library. http://www.watt-32.net/change.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These header files are a bit old/dated.  The usage of `extern inline` has changed with newer compilers.  `extern inline` *was* the preferred way for many years.  It worked fine on `gcc` but `clang` needed `static inline`

Now, even `gcc` wants `static inline` even with -O2 or you get what you're seeing.  Since you're recompiling from source, you may have to edit the .h and change all of them to `static`.

I have boilerplate for my code that was `#define craigs_inline extern inline` and now I've switched it to `#define craigs_inline static inline` to keep the peace.

Note that I didn't investigate a compiler -foption_whatever that might obviate the need for this.  If you find you one, please send me a comment as I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I *just* found out about this while digging through the system headers, which use `extern __inline__ __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__))`. A comment in `<sys/cdefs.h>` notes that this attribute is equivalent to compiling with `-fgnu89-inline`. And yes, after recompiling the Watt32 library with this option, my test file also compiles without errors! :)

Comment: @user5434231 Thank _you_!!!  As Captain Kirk once said to Scotty:  _You've earned your pay for the week_

Comment: More info: In C, there was officially no `inline` before C99. GCC rolled their own ; and C99 inline has different behaviour for the same code than gnu89. A mess.  C++ is different again. [Summary here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline/216546#216546). This codebase is clearly written for gnu89 inline, but being compiled as C99.

Comment: My advice for portable code would be to not use inline functions in headers which are to be included from both C and C++ ; however in practice I think you would get away with using `static inline` in all dialects.

Comment: Yes, it's a mess.  My code does #ifdef's on CLANG, OPTIMIZE cplusplus GNUC etc, and defines abstract macros as mentioned in my answer.  There is one [and only one place] that it does this and _every_ other .h file uses the abstracts.  This has and does work.  So, not a mess.  For a new situation, I add new #ifdef's [and/or simplify].  The abstracts could be def'ed by autoconf, etc. BTW, I defined the abstracts on the very first day I wrote an inline [~20 years ago] because I saw the problem up front.  Not unique, others do INLINE similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)?

Comment: It looks like a linker error to me.  Perhaps compile with gcc -c first to compile only - that should prove it is the library linking that is failing..