# how gcc compiler will link the inline functions at compilation

Tags: c, gcc, inline

I'm trying to understand how the inline functions are linked at linker.

here is the code snippet, how i am trying to check.

**inline.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"inline.h"
extern inline void in_fun();

void p_fun(void)
{
    printf("in %s\n",__func__);
}

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    printf("main: a=%d at %p\n",a,&a);
    in_fun();
    printf("main: a=%d at %p\n",a,&a);
    p_fun();
}
```

**inline.h**

```
inline void in_fun(void)
{
    int a=10;
    printf("inline: a=%d at %p\n",a,&a);
}
```

From wikipedia i got the inline function definition

In the C and C++ programming languages, an inline function is one qualified with the keyword inline; this serves two purposes. Firstly, it serves as a compiler directive that suggests (but does not require) that the compiler substitute the body of the function inline by performing inline expansion, i.e. **by inserting the function code at the address of each function call**, thereby saving the overhead of a function call.

so from the above code i made the disassemble of main,
there for inline function it is also getting called with **call** instruction & for normal function is also getting called with **call** instruction.

here is the disassembled part of main function

```
0x0804840b <+0>:    push   ebp
0x0804840c <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x0804840e <+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048411 <+6>:    sub    esp,0x20
0x08048414 <+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x5
0x0804841c <+17>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
0x08048420 <+21>:   mov    eax,0x804854f
0x08048425 <+26>:   lea    ecx,[esp+0x1c]
0x08048429 <+30>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],ecx
0x0804842d <+34>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
0x08048431 <+38>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x08048434 <+41>:   call   0x80482f4 <printf@plt>
0x08048439 <+46>:   call   0x80483c4 <in_fun>
0x0804843e <+51>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
0x08048442 <+55>:   mov    eax,0x804854f
0x08048447 <+60>:   lea    ecx,[esp+0x1c]
0x0804844b <+64>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],ecx
0x0804844f <+68>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
0x08048453 <+72>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x08048456 <+75>:   call   0x80482f4 <printf@plt>
0x0804845b <+80>:   call   0x80483ee <p_fun>
0x08048460 <+85>:   leave  
0x08048461 <+86>:   ret
```

so i want to know how **inserting the function code at the address of each function call** is justified &  how fastly it is executing & why the inline functions are written in header files only.

can any one can explain this.

Comment: This very informative answer may be useful to you: [extern inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline/216546#216546).

Comment: Note: in C when you specify `inline` it is a suggestion to the compiler that is not mandatory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That means, the gcc compiler will consider **inline** or not by default for c programs.

Comment: I suppose `p_fun` is not inlined because it calls `printf`, and there is so  much overhead caused by `printf` that inlining `p_fun` wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: What compilation options did you use?  Did you specify `-O` or `-O3` or anything similar?  If not, the compiler may not have bothered to inline the functions.  You could also experiment with adding a `static void s_fun(void)`, similar to your `p_fun()` but static, and call that — with optimization, it might well be inlined automatically.