# declarations for inline static functions

Tags: c, c99

For C99, is the following syntax legal when splitting up static inline functions into separate declarations and definitions?

foo.h:

```
#include "foo_decl.h"
#include "foo_def.h"
```

foo_decl.h:

```
#ifndef _FOO_DECL_H
#define _FOO_DECL_H

/* Here we document foo */
inline int foo(int x);

/* Here we document bar */
inline int bar(int x, int y);

#endif // _FOO_DECL_H
```

foo_def.h:

```
#ifndef _FOO_DEF_H
#define _FOO_DEF_H

inline static int foo(int x) { return x+3; }

inline static int bar(int x, int y) { return x-y+22; }

#endif // _FOO_DEF_H
```

The declaration is really useless to the compiler, but it serves a purpose for collecting documentation for functions in one place without getting cluttered by interspersed implementation details.

Or should `foo_decl.h` include the `static` keyword?

Comment: static AND inline should go in the `*.c` file, you don't need to declare a static signature outside its compilation unit, the whole point of static is that it is only available in the compilation unit of which it was compiled.

Comment: @self: actually it depends on the compiler, e.g. for some versions of gcc you need `static inline` in the header, otherwise debug builds fail due to multiple definitions at link time.

Comment: @self -- the intent is to place into a .h file for inclusion in multiple compilation units as per Paul R's comment.

Comment: @self `static inline` in a header is the only way to have the code compatible with both ISO C and GNU C, [see here for detail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/1505939)

Comment: `inline` definitions in a .c file are completely pointless. The only use that  `inline`  has is that you can put a definition in a .h file such that several translation units see it.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Not really. Yo might want to document the function is a critical path. Without `static`, this is even vital to provide a callable definition for the function in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour according to 6.2.2/7:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

The line `inline int foo(int x);` declares `foo` to have external linkage (6.2.2/5), but `static int foo(int x) {` declares `foo` to have internal linkage.

If you really want to do this then the versions in `foo_decl.h` and `foo_def.h` must either both have `static`, or neither have `static`. In the latter case exactly one `.c` file must have `extern inline int foo(int x);`.