# Assimp elaborated type refers to typedef

Tags: c, matrix, assimp

I am receiving the above error when trying to create a function that takes struct aiMatrix4x4* or any other aiStructs, I don't know why, I can my models properly, I just cannot make a function with the above struct as parameters for some odd reason, here's the code i question, I can even isolate it and it still gives me the error...

```
#include <math.h>
#include <assimp/cimport.h>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
#include <assimp/matrix4x4.h>

// A Bit Later in the Code

static inline void mat4x4_loadassimp(mat4x4 M, struct aiMatrix4x4* a);
```

I am using the latest assimp compiled from source... with C. Using clang as the compiler.

Comment: I can't help you more that the dev of the project https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/1126. But I have not problem with `struct aiMatrix4x4 *a`, I only get `unknow mat4x4`.

Comment: Seem that the `typedef` is only available with C++.

Comment: You should post your real code because I can't reproduce with this [mcve].

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/kaArY

Comment: you include "linmath.h" that differs from you mcve. We can't solve this problem is you don't have the exact same code.

Comment: @Stargateur, linmath I promise has nothing to do with the assimp matrix, i had the issue even before I included linmath.h, albeit at this point, I opened an issue on the assimp library github page so I think I'll close this thread as at this point, I'll let the developper handle it, thank you anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/matrix4x4_8h.html#details). `aiMatrix4x4` is a typedef in C++.

So you can't write `struct aiMatrix4x4` in C++.

```
static inline void mat4x4_loadassimp(mat4x4 M, aiMatrix4x4 *a);
```

If you compile in C, you must write:

```
static inline void mat4x4_loadassimp(mat4x4 M, struct aiMatrix4x4 *a);
```

Comment: `inline` changes the semantics of the code w.r.t. the one definition rule.  You're probably talking about the decision whether or not to inline the function.

Comment: @M.M Can you link me some doc? I don't know what you are taking about.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline)

Comment: Actually, when i remove the struct setting, it tells me that I must use the struct identifier