# C99 'extern inline' in library used by C++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11, inline, c99

There seem to be plenty of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline?rq=1) clarifying the semantics of C99's `inline` specification, with a single `extern` translation unit / implementation. If a C++ program / library was to use a C(99) API, with an `extern "C" {}` wrapper, will it honour the 'single implementation' semantics of the library?

If the C++ compiler is still free to create multiple instantiations as needed, is it required to recognise the C implementation as just another instance, via linker magic, or is this implementation-specific?

From my understanding, the only *portable* interoperable solution seems to be a `static inline` specification. Is C99's `extern inline` fundamentally incompatible with C++? (specifically C++11 and above)

Comment: Edge case but I would consider swapping [tag:c] for [tag:language-lawyer], it attracts the standards-minded folks.

Comment: Not an answer, but if the same compiler was used both to compile the C and C++ code, I think it is likely to do the sane thing. While C++11 considers C99 a normative reference, I'm not sure what it means regarding the same keyword interoperability .

Comment: @StoryTeller - I would *expect* the C library to emit a symbol, and C++ code to emit 'weak' symbols, on most platforms using the same compiler, thereby doing the expected thing. But I'm interested in portability of the C library. I'm pretty much resigned to the fact that this is implementation-specific.