# calls to syslog() replaced with __syslog_chk()?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am trying to use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept calls to `syslog()`. I could successfully try that on one of *my* program and it worked.

When I tried it on a pre-built application (came via a Debian package), I observed that it invokes `__syslog_chk()`, on inspecting the source of the package, there were no direct calls to `__syslog_chk()` !

So, it ought to be the compiler [whichever was used],  changed the `syslog()`s to `__syslog_chk()` ?
I tried with `gcc` options `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`, `-O2` etc. None of them seemed to make this change! Which option forces use of `__chk()` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it ought to be the compiler [whichever was used], changed the syslog()s to __syslog_chk() ?

Yes, you might say that, as always inspect the sources. https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/sys/syslog.h -> `#if __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 0 && defined __fortify_function` -> https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/bits/syslog.h#L31 .  The `__fortify_function` is a `extern inline`, and you might want to read about `extern inline` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html [What does extern inline do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/what-does-extern-inline-do) . The compiler chooses the `inline` version of the function instead of the `extern` one, and inlines the call, making it `__syslog_chk`.

> Which option forces use of __chk() function ?

Using `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`. Inspect the `syslog.h` of your system - it's all there. Good IDE come with a "jump to definition" functionality which greatly enhances browsing in such cases.

Note that https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/misc/syslog.c#L112 `syslog`->`__syslog`->`__vsyslog_chk` and `__syslog_chk` -> `__vsyslog_chk`. You might just `LD_PRELOAD` `__vsyslog_chk` to handle all cases.